# The transaction failed because of low gas but my eth was not refunded on mew

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet

I used mew to swap eth for btc to send them to an ico. The transaction failed because of low gas but I did not get my eth back and my balance is showing as zero.

TxHash:0x65d0f371cdf394943b98efb1b697bb591ea6ac3d9a081937b90d4105f3ad4959

How will I get my eth back?

Comment: "I used mew to swap eth for btc" Could you explain more? What was doing the swap? The transaction failed, so it had no effect on the balance of the calling account. But if the swap was being done through some sort of exchange, they may have improperly updated your balance in their system. (And you'll need to talk to their support team to resolve the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

MyEtherWallet is a wallet that provides some exchange through a third party services. You should contact MEW with the full details of the exchange like intervining accounts, destination addresses, etc.

Also you should **never** contribute to an ICO from an account you do not own the private key, unless the wallet has explicit support for the ICO.

Comment: MyEtherWallet isn't a custodial wallet, you're the only one that has the private key and you're the only one with control of your account. You can call any function code and participate in any ICO from MyEtherWallet.

Comment: @flygoing MEW allow to swap ETH and BTC through third party services. You can convert your BTC and send the ETH to an arbitrary recipient. From the description and Tx Hash provided it send the resulting ETH to the ICO Sale directly, and it failed because out of gas. Event if it didn't failed it will be impossible to access said tokens because the sender address if from the third party service.

Answer (score 0):

ETH refund must be made to Bity.com account.
Honestly, it never came out of there. :)
It was transferred from your MEW account to bity.com, but apparently it did not go to the ICO project from there. You can solve the problem by contacting Bity.Com.